# Automatically name an XP node from DHCP/DNS

Tags: windows-xp, dhcp

So one of the things that many (most?) Linux distributions can do is to either accept the dhcp option telling it what its node name should be, and/or do a reverse-lookup on the ip address it has been given via dhcp and apply its initial node name from that answer.

Is there a way to make XP do either of those?

Comment: Can you add some detail as to why you want to rename the machines from DHCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately. The computer name is set in the registry, and it's not going to change based on DHCP or a reverse DNS lookup.

(I suppose, technically, it could be possible, but I'd guess you'd need a reboot after setting the name.)

(Okay, okay-- I suppose this wouldn't be *that* hard to do, but I'm fairly sure you're going to incur a reboot each time the name changes. Still, you could do this in a startup script, and if the name doesn't change, just boot as normal. Hey... this might be fun to write!)

Answer (score 0):

**Its possible** with a little help of wsname: http://mystuff.clarke.co.nz/MyStuff/wsname.asp

1. collect the name and mac-address from your dhcpd.leases or write them on your own in a file (Mac2DnsName.txt") on a samba-share. Each line holds he mac-address and the name like this: `00508B052AE8 = Computer1`
2. write a autostart-batch with this content:  `wsname  /RDF:"\\pdc\netlogon\Mac2DnsName.txt" /DFK:$MAC`

So everytime the machine boots wsname looks into this file. If the PC-name differs (e.g. after a cloning-run), it changes the name and does a reboot. If the name doesn`t differ, nothing happens.

Runs like a charm here in several schools.